# Determining saftey of Javascript from other authors, with example

Tags: javascript, security

I would like to know what kind of safety measurements do you take into consideration when importing javascript code from another author (stated free to use) into your project.
So if you came across a [super simple navigation template from codepen](https://codepen.io/ErezT/pen/ORYEjg), after I d/l it I found out it didn't work unless it uses a js file that contained an `XMLHttpRequest` (why would you need an http request for this template, I don't know) here's [another example](https://codepen.io/fabienequant/pen/VKyRkV) with a lot of var declarations and replaces.

So to reiterate my question, other than seeing if this following code is dodgy, I would also like to know why would you need an http request for a simple website like this and what measurement would you take when you use other people's code, or maybe you never use other people code?

```
!function () {
    function e(e, r) {
        return [].slice.call((r || document).querySelectorAll(e))
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        var r = window.StyleFix = {
            link: function (e) {
                try {
                    if ("stylesheet" !== e.rel || e.hasAttribute("data-noprefix"))return
                } catch (t) {
                    return
                }
                var n, i = e.href || e.getAttribute("data-href"),
                    a = i.replace(/[^\/]+$/, ""), o = (/^[a-z]{3,10}:/.exec(a) || [""])[0],
                    s = (/^[a-z]{3,10}:\/\/[^\/]+/.exec(a) || [""])[0], l = /^([^?]*)\??/.exec(i)[1], u = e.parentNode, p = new XMLHttpRequest;
                p.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    4 === p.readyState && n()
                }, n = function () {
                    var t = p.responseText;
                    if (t && e.parentNode && (!p.status || p.status < 400 || p.status > 600)) {
                        if (t = r.fix(t, !0, e), a) {
                            t = t.replace(/url\(\s*?((?:"|')?)(.+?)\1\s*?\)/gi, function (e, r, t) {
                                return /^([a-z]{3,10}:|#)/i.test(t) ? e : /^\/\//.test(t) ? 'url("' + o + t + '")' : /^\//.test(t) ? 'url("' + s + t + '")' : /^\?/.test(t) ? 'url("' + l + t + '")' : 'url("' + a + t + '")'
                            });
                            var n = a.replace(/([\\\^\$*+[\]?{}.=!:(|)])/g, "\\$1");
                            t = t.replace(RegExp("\\b(behavior:\\s*?url\\('?\"?)" + n, "gi"), "$1")
                        }
                        var i = document.createElement("style");
                        i.textContent = t, i.media = e.media, i.disabled = e.disabled, i.setAttribute("data-href", e.getAttribute("href")), u.insertBefore(i, e), u.removeChild(e), i.media = e.media
                    }
                };
                try {
                    p.open("GET", i), p.send(null)
                } catch (t) {
                    "undefined" != typeof XDomainRequest && (p = new XDomainRequest, p.onerror = p.onprogress = function () {
                    }, p.onload = n, p.open("GET", i), p.send(null))
                }
                e.setAttribute("data-inprogress", "")
            }, styleElement: function (e) {
                if (!e.hasAttribute("data-noprefix")) {
                    var t = e.disabled;
                    e.textContent = r.fix(e.textContent, !0, e), e.disabled = t
                }
            }, styleAttribute: function (e) {
                var t = e.getAttribute("style");
                t = r.fix(t, !1, e), e.setAttribute("style", t)
            }, process: function () {
                e("style").forEach(StyleFix.styleElement), e("[style]").forEach(StyleFix.styleAttribute)
            }, register: function (e, t) {
                (r.fixers = r.fixers || []).splice(void 0 === t ? r.fixers.length : t, 0, e)
            }, fix: function (e, t, n) {
                for (var i = 0; i < r.fixers.length; i++)e = r.fixers[i](e, t, n) || e;
                return e
            }, camelCase: function (e) {
                return e.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (e, r) {
                    return r.toUpperCase()
                }).replace("-", "")
            }, deCamelCase: function (e) {
                return e.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function (e) {
                    return "-" + e.toLowerCase()
                })
            }
        };
        !function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
            }, 10), document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", StyleFix.process, !1)
        }()
    }
}(), function (e) {
    function r(e, r, n, i, a) {
        if (e = t[e], e.length) {
            var o = RegExp(r + "(" + e.join("|") + ")" + n, "gi");
            a = a.replace(o, i)
        }
        return a
    }

    if (window.StyleFix && window.getComputedStyle) {
        var t = window.PrefixFree = {
            prefixCSS: function (e, n) {
                var i = t.prefix;
                if (t.functions.indexOf("linear-gradient") > -1 && (e = e.replace(/(\s|:|,)(repeating-)?linear-gradient\(\s*(-?\d*\.?\d*)deg/gi, function (e, r, t, n) {
                        return r + (t || "") + "linear-gradient(" + (90 - n) + "deg"
                    })), e = r("functions", "(\\s|:|,)", "\\s*\\(", "$1" + i + "$2(", e), e = r("keywords", "(\\s|:)", "(\\s|;|\\}|$)", "$1" + i + "$2$3", e), e = r("properties", "(^|\\{|\\s|;)", "\\s*:", "$1" + i + "$2:", e), t.properties.length) {
                    var a = RegExp("\\b(" + t.properties.join("|") + ")(?!:)", "gi");
                    e = r("valueProperties", "\\b", ":(.+?);", function (e) {
                        return e.replace(a, i + "$1")
                    }, e)
                }
                return n && (e = r("selectors", "", "\\b", t.prefixSelector, e), e = r("atrules", "@", "\\b", "@" + i + "$1", e)), e = e.replace(RegExp("-" + i, "g"), "-"), e = e.replace(/-\*-(?=[a-z]+)/gi, t.prefix)
            }, property: function (e) {
                return (t.properties.indexOf(e) ? t.prefix : "") + e
            }, value: function (e) {
                return e = r("functions", "(^|\\s|,)", "\\s*\\(", "$1" + t.prefix + "$2(", e), e = r("keywords", "(^|\\s)", "(\\s|$)", "$1" + t.prefix + "$2$3", e)
            }, prefixSelector: function (e) {
                return e.replace(/^:{1,2}/, function (e) {
                    return e + t.prefix
                })
            }, prefixProperty: function (e, r) {
                var n = t.prefix + e;
                return r ? StyleFix.camelCase(n) : n
            }
        };
        !function () {
            var e = {}, r = [], n = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, null), i = document.createElement("div").style, a = function (t) {
                if ("-" === t.charAt(0)) {
                    r.push(t);
                    var n = t.split("-"), i = n[1];
                    for (e[i] = ++e[i] || 1; n.length > 3;) {
                        n.pop();
                        var a = n.join("-");
                        o(a) && -1 === r.indexOf(a) && r.push(a)
                    }
                }
            }, o = function (e) {
                return StyleFix.camelCase(e) in i
            };
            if (n.length > 0)for (var s = 0; s < n.length; s++)a(n[s]); else for (var l in n)a(StyleFix.deCamelCase(l));
            var u = {uses: 0};
            for (var p in e) {
                var f = e[p];
                u.uses < f && (u = {prefix: p, uses: f})
            }
            t.prefix = "-" + u.prefix + "-", t.Prefix = StyleFix.camelCase(t.prefix), t.properties = [];
            for (var s = 0; s < r.length; s++) {
                var l = r[s];
                if (0 === l.indexOf(t.prefix)) {
                    var c = l.slice(t.prefix.length);
                    o(c) || t.properties.push(c)
                }
            }
            "Ms" != t.Prefix || "transform" in i || "MsTransform" in i || !("msTransform" in i) || t.properties.push("transform", "transform-origin"), t.properties.sort()
        }(), function () {
            function e(e, r) {
                return i[r] = "", i[r] = e, !!i[r]
            }

            var r = {
                "linear-gradient": {property: "backgroundImage", params: "red, teal"},
                calc: {property: "width", params: "1px + 5%"},
                element: {property: "backgroundImage", params: "#foo"},
                "cross-fade": {property: "backgroundImage", params: "url(a.png), url(b.png), 50%"}
            };
            r["repeating-linear-gradient"] = r["repeating-radial-gradient"] = r["radial-gradient"] = r["linear-gradient"];
            var n = {
                initial: "color",
                "zoom-in": "cursor",
                "zoom-out": "cursor",
                box: "display",
                flexbox: "display",
                "inline-flexbox": "display",
                flex: "display",
                "inline-flex": "display",
                grid: "display",
                "inline-grid": "display",
                "min-content": "width"
            };
            t.functions = [], t.keywords = [];
            var i = document.createElement("div").style;
            for (var a in r) {
                var o = r[a], s = o.property, l = a + "(" + o.params + ")";
                !e(l, s) && e(t.prefix + l, s) && t.functions.push(a)
            }
            for (var u in n) {
                var s = n[u];
                !e(u, s) && e(t.prefix + u, s) && t.keywords.push(u)
            }
        }(), function () {
            function r(e) {
                return a.textContent = e + "{}", !!a.sheet.cssRules.length
            }

            var n = {
                ":read-only": null,
                ":read-write": null,
                ":any-link": null,
                "::selection": null
            }, i = {keyframes: "name", viewport: null, document: 'regexp(".")'};
            t.selectors = [], t.atrules = [];
            var a = e.appendChild(document.createElement("style"));
            for (var o in n) {
                var s = o + (n[o] ? "(" + n[o] + ")" : "");
                !r(s) && r(t.prefixSelector(s)) && t.selectors.push(o)
            }
            for (var l in i) {
                var s = l + " " + (i[l] || "");
                !r("@" + s) && r("@" + t.prefix + s) && t.atrules.push(l)
            }
            e.removeChild(a)
        }(), t.valueProperties = ["transition", "transition-property"], e.className += " " + t.prefix, StyleFix.register(t.prefixCSS)
    }
}(document.documentElement);
```

Here is the code.

Answer (score 2):

> why would you need an http request for a simple website like this

You don't. The effect on the page is done entirely with CSS. You can delete all the JS and it still works.

The JavaScript is a minified (which is why it's so hard to read) version of [this library](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree), which is a complicated and brittle attempt to adapt CSS styles for older browsers that require browser-specific property prefixes for some of the newer CSS features. It has to do XMLHttpRequests in order to fetch the stylesheet files and fiddle with them.

It's unclear why the example code has bothered use that library, since the CSS already contains the prefixed versions of the properties. But that's the joy and curse of grabbing random code off the internet, you have no idea if it's at all sensible...

> I would like to know what kind of safety measurements do you take into consideration when importing javascript code from another author (stated free to use) into your project.

There's no magic bullet. You have to read and understand what all the code is doing, or you have to completely trust the author of the code (and the operators of the service hosting it, if you're linking it directly from a third-party server like a CDN).